# How to get value from <div> tag when input change in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using WMD library to create an editor. When I input data into `text area`, my `preview` change data such as preview content from the input.

**My question:** Can I get content from the content of `div preview`? .How to do that?

```
<textarea id="wmd-input" ng-model="params.content" class="wmd-panel"></textarea>
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-preview" ></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by contnet of di preview?

Comment: @Sajeetharan : Example I input multiple `code` lines into `text area`, preview area can generate to Html code such as `<pre><code>..</code></pre>`. I want to access this by $scope from controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **[angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)** delegates to Angular's built-in subset of jQuery,

```
 $scope.content= angular.element(document.querySelector('#wmd-preview'));
 alert($scope.content);
```

Comment: Where's exactly I can put this code into? Is the controller?

Comment: `[object Object]` when I alert :) @Sajeetharan :)

Comment: Check the updated plunker it displays inside the div https://plnkr.co/edit/1FQC0hujXHqxdSmJdOdX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can output your textarea value with `$scope` using `ng-bind-html-unsafe` inside your `code` HTML element. It does work like in this -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tx9Lm5k3/5/):

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <textarea id="wmd-input" ng-model="params.content" class="wmd-panel"></textarea>
  <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-preview">
    <pre>
      <code ng-bind="params.content"></code>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### App & Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.params = {
    content: "<h1>Hello World</h1>"
  }
}
```

#### Output

```
>   <html>
>       <head></head>
>       <body>
>             <h1>Hello World</h1>
>       <body>
>   </html>
```

Comment: OP is asking the other way

Comment: Mhm, I think its the right way. Input in textarea is shown as HTML Code output in `div`. @Ntlzz93 what do you say?

Comment: @lin : No. I want to access the content of div tag from the controller. Is This clear ?

Comment: Well, i already access it with `$scope.params.content`. You can also do this. Whats the problem with it?